# Dudas con Forecast y auto.arima predicción

Tags: r, rstudio, predicción

soy nuevo en la comunidad y con R.
Estoy intentando hacer una predicción sobre el número de casos de covid en mi municipio en base a la fecha, pero me está dando problemas y no acabo de entender por qué.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Adjunto el código que hasta ahora hice:

```
# Carga datos:
datos_covid<-read.delim(file.choose(),header = T, sep = ";", fill=TRUE)
View(datos_covid)
datos2<-datos_covid


# Hacemos plot(), para ver el grafico:
plot(datos2)

# Cargamos paquete de datos ggplot:
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

# Anadimos mas detalles al grafico:
ggplot(data=datos2,
       aes(x=FECHA,
           y=NUMCASOS, group=1))+
  geom_line(colour="red")+
  labs(x="FECHA", y="NUMERO CASOS",
       title="CASOS COVID MUNICIPIO POR FECHA")

class(datos2)

# Cargamos libreria Forecast:
install.packages("forecast")
library(forecast)

# Ajustamos los datos al eje de las X. Es decir, especificamos la columna del NUMERO DE CASOS,   que es la que queremos predecir:
datos3<-datos2$NUMCASOS
View(datos3)

# La data sera el eje de las Y. Es decir, convertir unos datos en clase temporal:
install.packages("zoo") 
require(zoo)

# Indicamos el inicio y el final de los datos en la grafica, para predecir:
start=as.Date("2020-02-01")
start=as.yearmon(start)
end = as.yearmon(as.Date("2020-12-31"));end

datos4<-ts(datos3,start=start,end=end,frequency=12)

# Ver que aspecto tiene el objeto
datos4
ts.plot(datos4)

# Predicciones:
mod1<-auto.arima(datos4)

# Se coge el 75% de los primeros datos (DATOS DE ENTRENAMIENTO) 
train_datos<-datos4[1:573]
View(train_datos)

prediccion <- forecast(train_datos, h=10, model=mod1)
plot(prediccion)

# Cogemos los registros restantes.
lines(x=seq(573, 839, 1), y=datos4[573:839], col="red")
```

Al realizar este último paso, hay datos que me salen en blanco (NA).
Hice la prueba con otros datos y una menor cantidad de observaciones (unas 30, más o menos) y no tuve este problema.

Así es como se muestran los datos csv, hasta 839 obs.

```
FECHA   SEXODESCRIPCION SEXOCODIGO  NUMCASOS
09/03/2020  Hombre  0   1
10/03/2020  Mujer   1   3
10/03/2020  Hombre  0   4
11/03/2020  Hombre  0   2
11/03/2020  Mujer   1   2
12/03/2020  Mujer   1   4
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme. Gracias por adelantado. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien mi conocimiento de estadística es muy básico, voy a señalarte algunos aspecto de tu análisis que me parece pueden estar trayéndote problemas.

- Pareciera que no tienes un serie de tiempo, sino dos, la que corresponde a hombres y la de mujeres. Deberías tratar ambas por separado o en su defecto sumar ambas observaciones en un número de casos general. Si la tratas como una sola serie, terminas teniendo dos observaciones por fecha.
- El otro problema grave, que veo es que extiendes la serie de tiempo al 12 de diciembre, ¿por qué? si no tienes datos aún para esos días futuros. En este caso, lo que hace `ts()` es reciclar los valores desde los primeros días.
- El otro problema es que defines una frecuencia mensual, cuando por los datos me doy cuenta que tiene una serie diaria. Podrías eventualmente sumarizar mensualmente, pero serían unos poco meses, me parece que es mejor quedarse con una serie diaria.

Voy a reproducir algo parecido a lo que estás intentando:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)

covid.data <- read.csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv", na.strings = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

covid.data %>% 
  filter(countryterritoryCode == 'ARG') %>% 
  mutate(FECHA = as.Date(dateRep,"%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  select(FECHA, NUMCASOS = cases) %>% 
  complete(FECHA = seq.Date(min(FECHA), max(FECHA), by='day'), fill=list(NUMCASOS = 0)) %>% 
  group_by(FECHA) %>% 
  summarize(NUMCASOS = sum(NUMCASOS)) -> datos

datos

# A tibble: 252 x 2
   FECHA      NUMCASOS
   <date>        <dbl>
 1 2020-03-04        1
 2 2020-03-05        0
 3 2020-03-06        1
 4 2020-03-07        6
 5 2020-03-08        1
 6 2020-03-09        3
 7 2020-03-10        0
 8 2020-03-11        7
 9 2020-03-12        0
10 2020-03-13       12
# … with 242 more rows
```

Partimos de datos de casos totales de COVID, en este ejemplo de Argentina y sin desagregación por Sexo. El proceso anterior lo que asegura es tener una serie completa de fechas, una sola observación por día sin huecos.

Esto es un parte fundamental del análisis, los datos, como en este ejemplo, tienen algunos faltantes y eventualmente podrían tener más de una observación por día, con `complete()` llenamos los huecos con el valor 0 (lo cual tal vez no es lo mejor, pero es peor dejar el hueco) y con un `group_by() +  summarize()` por las dudas, sumamos por día, en caso de tener más de un registro.

Con estos datos, ahora si podemos construir una serie de tiempo:

```
serie <- ts(datos$NUMCASOS, start = min(datos$FECHA), end = max(datos$FECHA), frequency=1)
```

Desde el primer día, hasta el último, respetando la frecuencia diaria. Con estos datos replico lo mismo que estas haciendo:

```
modelo <- auto.arima(serie)
prediccion <- forecast(serie, h=60, model=modelo)
plot(prediccion)
```

Y planteo una proyección de 60 días (`h = 60`), el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Patricio, muchas gracias. 
Ahora lo entendí y me sirvió lo que me dijo. Me gustaría preguntarle algo sobre este gráfico que me muestra al final. Los datos que aparecen en el eje X: 18350, 18400... ¿qué son? ¿Sería posible modificarlos por la fecha exacte o por un mes concreto?

Espero su respuesta. Gracias nuevamente
Saludos

Comment: Hola @David, esos números tal como construímos la serie, es como internamente se guardan las fechas en un `ts`, y es el número de días desde el 1/1/1970. En ese sentido, el  `ts` e un objeto bastante básico, puedes intentar usar `xts` que incorpora varias mejoras y es compatible con el código que dependea de un `ts`, sino seguramente es más cómodo empezar planteando la serie desde el día 1 al n: `serie <- ts(datos$NUMCASOS, start = 1, end = length(datos$FECHA), frequency=1) ` en cuyo caso la serie se representará  del día 1 hasta el número de día de la predicción.

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias Patricio